# Mapping Excel rows to model

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel file and each row within the sheet represents an employee's data.

I am trying to find a cleaner way to map each row to a `model` object:

```
public IList<Employee> ReadEmployees(byte[] file, string companyId)
{
    var employees = new List<Employee>();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(file))
    {
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
            for (var rowNumber = 3; rowNumber <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
            {
                //---- Trying to retrieve the row data in an elegant way----
                var employee = GetEmployeeRowSummary(worksheet, rowNumber, companyId);
                employees.Add(employee);
            }
        }
    }

    return employees;
}
```

I was kind of hoping to use something like `auto-mapper` but don't know if that would be the best way (maybe create a Custom Resolver).

Is there a better way of mapping excel rows to an model? The way I am doing it currently seems like a maintenance issue.

```
private static Employee GetEmployeeRowSummary(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int rowNumber, string companyId)
{
    var employeeId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    return new Employee
           {
               CompanyId = companyId,
               EmployeeId = employeeId,
               EmployeeNumber = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].GetValue<string>(),
               FirstName = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].GetValue<string>(),
               LastName = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].GetValue<string>(),
               BirthDate = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].GetValue<DateTime>(),
               AppointmentDate = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].GetValue<DateTime>(),
               CompanyRunFrequencyId = 9,
               JobTitle = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 8].GetValue<string>(),
               DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
               EmployeeAddress = new List<EmployeeAddress>
                                 {
                                    new EmployeeAddress
                                    {
                                        EmployeeId = employeeId,
                                        StreetNumber = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 9].GetValue<int>(),
                                        Suburb = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 11].GetValue<string>(),
                                        City = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 12].GetValue<string>(),
                                        PostalCode = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 13].GetValue<int>()
                                    }
                                 }
           };
}
```

Comment: Is this the code as you currently use it? Maintenance issues aside, does it work to your satisfaction?

Comment: Yes this is my current code, and working

Answer (score 4):

The indentation needs to be mentioned. Hopefully it's just an accidental tabs vs spaces issue that caused it to render this way, ...but I'm not seeing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters, so... the indentation needs to be mentioned, becauase this is not normal:

> ```
> public IList<Employee> ReadEmployees(byte[] file, string companyId)
>         {
> ```

Expected:

```
public IList<Employee> ReadEmployees(byte[] file, string companyId)
{
```

Just like you have here:

> ```
>             using (var stream = new MemoryStream(file))
>             {
> ```

And here:

> ```
>                     for (var rowNumber = 3; rowNumber <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
>                     {
> ```

Now, with that cleared, the `GetEmployeeRowSummary` method looks much cleaner already:

```
private static Employee GetEmployeeRowSummary(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int rowNumber, string companyId)

{
    var employeeId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    return new Employee
    {
        CompanyId = companyId,
        EmployeeId = employeeId,
        EmployeeNumber = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1].GetValue<string>(),
        FirstName = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2].GetValue<string>(),
        LastName = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3].GetValue<string>(),
        BirthDate = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4].GetValue<DateTime>(),
        AppointmentDate = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 5].GetValue<DateTime>(),
        CompanyRunFrequencyId = 9,
        JobTitle = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 8].GetValue<string>(),
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
        EmployeeAddress = new List<EmployeeAddress>
        {
            new EmployeeAddress
            {
                EmployeeId = employeeId,
                StreetNumber = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 9].GetValue<int>(),
                Suburb = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 11].GetValue<string>(),
                City = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 12].GetValue<string>(),
                PostalCode = worksheet.Cells[rowNumber, 13].GetValue<int>()
            }
       }
   };
}
```

Consistent indentation is fundamental for clean, readable code.

But readability isn't the biggest problem here: the repeated calls to `worksheet.Cells` and `{Range?}.GetValue` are.

I'm not sure what `ExcelPackage` is, but it's definitely not VSTO, so *maybe* this isn't as much of a problem, but invoking `worksheet.Cells[...].GetValue<...>()` is spawning a RCW (Runtime Callable Wrapper - a .NET wrapper object to access a COM object) whose reference isn't captured, and thus could be leaking the object reference. If you were using VSTO, there would very likely be a "ghost" EXCEL.EXE process lingering in *Task Manager* forever, well after your application happily terminated.

In any case, working directly with worksheet cells is THE slowest thing you can do, whether in VBA or C# through COM interop, whether it be through VSTO or any other library.

Again I don't know what `ExcelPackage` is nor what this API has to offer, but in the native Excel object model `Range.Value`, when the `Range` object represents multiple cells, gives you a 2D variant array (`object[,]` in .NET) - if all you're ever interested in is the values that are in the cells (as seems to be the case), then you don't need to deal with worksheets and cells and `.GetValue<T>()`.

So instead of looping through rows:

> ```
> for (var rowNumber = 3; rowNumber <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
> ```

Grab the values array (not sure what the syntax would be with this API - if your library doesn't allow you to grab a 2D array of values, drop that library and use VSTO):

```
var values = worksheet.Range(worksheet.Cells[3, 1], worksheet.Cells[lastRow, 13]).Value;
```

The idea is to get a `Range` object that encompasses all the cells you're interested in. Maybe that's everything from row 3 to `worksheet.Dimension.End.Row`, but even without knowing the slightest thing about this particular API I would fear that `worksheet.Dimension.End.Row` yields something like 1,048,576 - which is very very very unlikely the *actual* number of rows you need to care about.

With the Excel object model, you'd do something like `sheet.Range("A" & sheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to get the last interesting row (aka `lastRow`), and use that row number to make the "interesting range" from which to read the values.

Now that you have a 2D array that contains all the values, `GetEmployeeRowSummary` doesn't make much sense anymore: we don't care for a `rowNumber`, and we don't need a `ExcelWorksheet` reference anymore.

In fact all we need is a "row slice" of the 2D array, by copying the row to a new array ([this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51241629/1188513) looks like it):

```
public T[] GetRow(T[,] matrix, int rowNumber)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, matrix.GetLength(1))
            .Select(x => matrix[rowNumber, x])
            .ToArray();
}

private static Employee ReadEmployee(object[] row, string companyId)
{
    var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    return new Employee
    {
        CompanyId = companyId,
        EmployeeId = id,
        EmployeeNumber = (string)row[1],
        FirstName = (string)row[2],
        LastName = (string)row[3],
        BirthDate = (DateTime)row[4],
        //...
    };
}
```

As for mapping the properties automatically, I'm not a fan. *Something, somewhere* needs to do the mapping, and I'd much rather it be explicit in the code. Automatic mapping would need more metadata than just column indices - you'd likely need column names and data types, so instead of copying the cells to an array you'd be copying the cells to some `DataTable`, or have the mapper understand what an Excel `Range` or `ListObject` is... all of which sound like quite a lot of effort for an error-prone way to just list the properties at the left of an `=` operator. If your explicit casts blow up, you'll know why. If the automagic mapping blows up, pray the library throws meaningful exceptions.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, going to go through it now, but just to start the indentation was just a pasting issue. And the ExcelPackage is from a library called EPPlus, https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Comment: Ah, so there's no COM interop going on then, the package works directly with the OpenXML... which has pros ...and cons. Everything one knows about the Excel object model goes out the window, basically.